# bit twiddling : checking non-negative integers as difference of powers of 2

Tags: bit-manipulation, bit, boolean-logic, boolean-operations, boolean-algebra

Problem : To check  if a non-negative integer is of form `2^j - 2^k where j>=k>=0` i.e. difference of powers of 2.
My solution :  The number `n (say)` can be represented as contiguous sequence of 1's `for eg. 00011110`. I will turn off the contiguous sequence(right most) of 1's and do a zero check on `n`.
What I do here is that, `steps for solution 
00011110
00011111(turn on trailing 0's)
00000000(then turn off trailing 1's)`.
Using this formula `(x | (x - 1)) & ((x | (x - 1)) + 1)`.
But a more efficient formula(maybe because of less number of operation) which does not uses literals is `((x & -x) + x) & x` followed by a zero check. And I can't understand this but it's written it does the same thing, but just can't derive the formula from my result. Can someone explain this to me?

EDIT : 32-bit word, 2's complement

Comment: I don't think your formula is correct. Assuming two's complement, then take x = 2^3 - 2^0 = 7 = `0111b`. Then -x = `1001b`. `((x & -x) + x) & x` = `((0111 & 1001) + 0111) & 0111)` = `(1 + 0111) & 0111` = `1000 & 0111` = `0`. I can't see an error in that, but forgive me if I'm suffering a failure of logic.

Comment: @Tommy you're getting 0, and we are performing zero check, so what's the problem

Comment: @harold thanks for pointing out, I have edited

Comment: I want to know if there exists proper method to prove result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked for an algebraic proof connecting the two expressions, so here is one, but with some non-simple steps

```
((x | (x - 1)) + 1) & (x | (x - 1))
// rename x | (x - 1) into blsfill(x)
(blsfill(x) + 1) & blsfill(x)
// the trailing zeroes that get filled on the right side of the & don't matter,
// they end up being reset by the & anyway
(blsfill(x) + 1) & x
// filling the trailing zeroes and adding 1,
// is the same thing as skipping the trailing zeroes and adding the least-set-bit
(x + blsi(x)) & x
// rewrite blsi into elementary operations
(x + (x & -x)) & x
```

Answer (score 2):

Given that `-x` is `~x + 1`, if a number is of the form 2^j - 2^k then:

- `-x` = `2^k` plus all 1s >= 2^j, as carry will ripple up until it hits 2^k, then stop;
- hence `x & -x`= 2^k;
- hence `(x & -x) + x` = 2^k; and
- hence `((x & -x) + x) & x` = 0.

And you can work backwards along that logic:

- ((x & -x) + x) & x = 0 => no common bits between ((x & -x) + x) and x;
- no common bits between x and ((x & -x) + x) implies that for consecutive group of 1s in x, (x & -x) must have the lowest of those bits set and none of the others;
- ... and the only way to achieve that given the way that carry ripples is if there is only one consecutive group of 1s.

Comment: Can you show how `((x & -x) + x) & x` comes from `(x | (x - 1)) & (x | (x - 1) + 1)`